# Is it possible to nest a Schema within itself?

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to setup a comment system, where every comment can get a reply ad infinitum.

This is what I am trying to construct even though I am aware of the issue of referencing an object before it was created, but I posted this in hopes that someone might be able to suggest an alternative that won't crash the server.

```
var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    date: {type: Date},
    content: {type: String},
    replies: [commentSchema]  <---- this line is the kicker
});
```

Ideas?

Thanks

**Update:**

A solution I came up with is having this schema

```
var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    date: {type: Date},
    content: {type: String},
    replies: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}
});
```

Where in replies I store IDs of comments. 
Is this is best way to go?